# Hosts file - Alternative host when unavailable?

Tags: windows, hosts

In the windows hosts file, is it possible to have a site with multiple redirect hosts with different priorities, in case one is down?

Answer (score 1):

No. The hosts file is a simple flat file containing domain and IP address pairs only. The lookup service checks the host file first for a matching domain name and if one is found it uses the IP address specific in the file. There are no additional checks or balancing done during this lookup and no additional parameters are supported in the host definitions.